# Why does $M \equiv a^{p-1}M\pmod p$ implies $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

Why do we need that $\gcd(M,p)=1$ to say that:

$M \equiv a^{p-1}M\pmod p$ implies $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$?

Comment: Because it ensures $M$ has an inverse $\mod p$. Take for example $a^{p-1}\equiv 2$, $M=p$. Then $M\equiv a^{p-1}M\equiv 0\mod p$ yet $a^{p-1}\equiv 2\not\equiv 1\mod p$. Kinda like dividing by $0$, but in modular arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Otherwise, $p\mid M$. Then the assertion $M\equiv a^{p-1}M\pmod p$ would be true for any $a$. And if this assertion is *always* true, you can't deduce that $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$ happens *sometimes*.

Comment: Why is the assertion true for any a if p divides M? I do not see this.

Comment: @WinstonCherf If $p\mid M$, then both numbers $M$ and $a^{p-1}M$ are multiples of $p$ and therefore $p\mid M-a^{p-1}M$.

Comment: Ok clean. But has it also something to do whit the inverse?

Comment: @WinstonCherf Yes, a bit. If $\gcd(M,p)=1$, then $M$ has an inverse $\pmod p$. You can use this fact to prove that $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod p$.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, $p \mid M$, so cancellation of $M \equiv 0 \pmod 0$ on both sides is not legitimate under $\pmod p$.  In fact, you have

$$M - a^{p-1}M = M (1 - a^{p-1}),$$

which is divisible by $p$ for whatever $a$, so you can't conclude anything about $a^{p-1} \pmod p$.